# .datepicker calendar selection not working 100% of the time

Tags: jquery, datepicker

This code seems to work normally except when a user selects a new date from the #startdate input field it only updates the #enddate field the first 2 times and on the 3rd it does nothing, not sure what exactly is causing the problem... if anyone would be able to spot the issue

I use the following imports, well thats what it says at the top of each one when I open them in notepad++

jquery-ui.css v1.11.2

jquery.js v1.10.2

jquery-ui.js v1.11.2

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#enddate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        onSelect: function (date){
            var dateliveend = $("#enddate").val();                  
            $('#dateliveend').html(dateliveend);    
        }
    });

    $("#startdate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: 365,
        onSelect: function (date) {
            var enddate = $('#startdate').datepicker('getDate'); 
            var startdate = $('#startdate').datepicker('getDate'); 

            startdate.setDate(startdate.getDate()); 
            enddate.setDate(enddate.getDate() + 28); 
            $('#enddate').datepicker('setDate', enddate);               

            $('#enddate').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', enddate);
            $('#enddate').datepicker('option', 'minDate', startdate);
        }
    });
});

    <input type="text" id="startdate" name="startdate" 
           value=" <?php echo date('d-M-Y', strtotime('+0 day') + 36000); ?>" readonly />

    <input type="text" id="enddate" name="deadline" 
           value=" <?php echo date('d-M-Y', strtotime('+28 day')  +36000); ?>" readonly />
```

I made a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RzD5Z/25/ which shows you the odd behaviour i'm experiencing

Comment: Works 70% of the time with the same date or different dates?

Comment: different dates, I click a date, it displays correctly, then I'll click a different date and sometimes have to open the datepicker a second time to click that date to get it to display

Comment: Where do you initialise the `#enddate` datepicker? Its probably not setting correctly if you are initialising it the same time as you set the enddate.

Comment: Please add your JS and CSS imports

Comment: added js and css imports and also the #enddate datepicker code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#enddate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
    minDate: 0,
    defaultDate: "+28d",
    maxDate: "+28d",

        });
$("#startdate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: 365,
    onClose: function () {

        var enddate = $('#startdate').datepicker('getDate'); 
        var startdate = new Date(enddate); 

        enddate.setDate(enddate.getDate()+28); 

        $('#enddate').datepicker('destroy');
        $('#enddate').datepicker();
        $('#enddate').datepicker('setDate', enddate);               

$('#enddate').datepicker('option', {
                                    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
                                    minDate: startdate, 
                                    maxDate: enddate
                                    });                 

    }
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="startdate" readonly />

<input type="text" id="enddate" readonly />
```

Here's the solution, I believe .datepicker had an issue with the initialisation so I destroy it before re-intialising. See fiddle - works great http://jsfiddle.net/RzD5Z/33/